# c# abstract class generic properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, abstract-class, poco

Consider the following code:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    #region Members

    private MyContext dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;

    #endregion

    protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    protected MyContext DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Remove(entity);
    }
```

I would like to replace the Delete method with the one below, since I would prefer to simply set a Deleted field to true in my object to indicated that it is deleted, instead of really deleting it.

```
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        entity.Deleted = true;
        dbset.Attach(entity);
        dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

I am using POCO entities and the Deleted property exists in all of them. However, in the code above entity is of type T, and T "doesn't know" that there is a Deleted property in all objects it can represent. What is the most elegant way to solve this?

By the way, I would like to access other fields (DateCreated, CreatedBy, DateModified and ModifiedBy) in a similar way in my abstract class.

**UPDATE**: I tried both the interface and the Abstract class solution, which seemed good at first, but then I got the following error message in both cases when compiling:

> Error 11  The type 'MyProject.Domain.Person' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyProject.Data.Infrastructure.RepositoryBase'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyProject.Domain.Person' to 'MyProject.Domain.AbstractEntity'.

And here is the code the error message is referring to:

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{ 
    public class PersonRepository : RepositoryBase<Person>, IPersonRepository
    {
        public PersonRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
            : base(databaseFactory)
        {
        }
    }

    public interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
    {

    }
}
```

Update 2:

I finally got it to work with the solution proposed by SLaks. I used an interface, and I modified the template generating all the POCO entities so that they would all derive from the following IEntity interface:

```
namespace MyProject.Domain
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
        System.DateTime CreatedDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        string CreatedBy
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        System.DateTime ModifiedDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        string ModifiedBy
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        bool Deleted
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Using an abstract entity class would be more complicated, since then all the properties in the abstract class would have to be overridden in the entity classes.

Comment: are you asking about `where T: class, MyClass` ?

Comment: @Tigran I tried that but I then got a compiling error message. See my update above.

Comment: The compiler error implies that Person doesn't inherit from AbstractEntity.  Did you forget to redefine its base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an interface with `Deleted` and other properties and implement it in your entity classes.
You can then constrain the generic type parameter to implement the interface.

Comment: I thought about this, but I was hoping for a simpler solution, since my POCO entities are generated automatically with a T4 template. I could of course modify the template, but T4 templates are quite new to me, and I am not sure how quick I could perform this modification.

Comment: You can implement the interface in a partial class in a different file without modifying the T4 (except to add the `partial` keyword if it's not there already)

Comment: You reminded me that I had already modified the template to add the "partial" keyword, so I thought it should not be that difficult to modify the template so that all entities would derive from IEntity (the interface you suggested adding), which I did and now everything is compiling fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Put your Deleted property into an interface (let's say, IDeleteable), and constrain the class with a generic constraint:

```
public interface IDeleteable { Boolean Deleted { get; set; } }

public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IDeleteable
```

EDIT: I thought this was implied, but you need to implement the interface in your entity classes, e.g.

```
public class Person : IDeleteable { ... }
```

Comment: @Chris_Shain I tried your solution, but then I ran into an error at compile time. See my update above to see my error.

Comment: @Chris_Shain Thanks, I did that finally and now it is working. I gave the right answer to SLaks, since he proposed the solution first, but I gave you +1 for writing some code in example. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use an abstract class for constraint

```
// from
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class

// to
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : AbstractEntity
```

Where **AbstractEntity** would have all the properties you need. Abstract class in contrast to an interface will allow you to provide some default implementation.

Comment: +1 for the justification of the use of an abstract base class.

Comment: @oleksii: I tried this solution, and it looked good, but then I ran into another problem at compile time. See my update above for the specific error message.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned using an interface or an abstract class. This is something I wholeheartedly recommend as well. If, for some dumb reason, that isn't possible, you could also use reflection:

```
entity.Deleted = true;
```

would be replaced with:

```
var type = typeof(T);
var property = type.GetProperty("Deleted");
property.SetValue(entity, true, null);
```